# Dialog Activity without layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I am trying to implement an alert dialog which is triggered by a service(in an Async thread). So I decided to implement alert dialog through an activity(ShowAlert.class). When the dialog is triggered using my background service, It is showing my default layout in the background. Even when I didn't set any layout in my alert activity(ShowAlert.class). Can anyone help me, how to remove that default layout from background.

**NOTE:** I am not Interested in Custom Layout.

[image]

CODE:

```
public class ShowAlert extends Activity
{
AlertDialog alertDialog;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("message");
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Title");
alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", 
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
      Intent positveActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeMap.class);
      // Sets the Activity to start in a new, empty task
      positveActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      positveActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      startActivity(positveActivity);

   }
});
alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", 
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       alertDialog.cancel();
     }
});

alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
}

}
```

Comment: Always show your code, when you posting programming questions.

Comment: check my answer, it will help you.

Answer (score 4):

Create an Activity

```
public class AlertActivity extends Activity {

    TextView dialog_title;
    TextView dialog_message;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature (Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow ().setBackgroundDrawableResource (android.R.color.transparent);
        setContentView (R.layout.view_custom_alert);

        dialog_title = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.dialog_title);
        dialog_message = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.dialog_message);

        dialog_title.setText ("Alert!");
        dialog_message.setText ("Reminder text here....                                                   ");
    }
}
```

In your manifest

```
<activity
        android:name="com.telmate.custom.AlertActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Comment: getWindow ().setBackgroundDrawableResource (android.R.color.transparent); This will solve the issue. thanks @Murtaza

Comment: `Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE` didn't work for me, I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46013274) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        dialog.setTitle("Title...");

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
```

Comment: Create an xml file whatever you want to show in it and pass it in as setContentView(R.layout.your_Custom_layout_file); Now you wont see the dialog like you are seeing now one more thing instead of creating activity you can show this dialog directly from your service there is no need to create activity. good luck.