# requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); not working

Tags: java, android

i have referred many questions....but not any answer working in my case....plz help me.....

```
package com.example.owner.bikeguard;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to make full screen activity

Comment: no...i just want to remove the appname/activitytitlebar (whole titlebar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this  to remove the appname/activitytitlebar from your activity

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
```

or in manifest file use `android:label=""` in your  like this

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

**apply this theme to remove whole title bar in your style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

or try this for full screen activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);
    }
```

Comment: status bar and action bar are totally different things

Answer (score 6):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  getSupportActionBar().hide();
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

this will hide the action bar completely

Comment: status bar and action bar are totally different things

Answer (score 5):

i've an easy way to do this.
You can simple achieve `NO_TITLE` for whole application by setting it to the `AppTheme`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
```

these tags for Actionbar

```
 <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

these is for No title

```
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

these is for FullScreen

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line after `setcontentview`

```
getSupportActionbar.hide()
```

Comment: status bar and action bar are totally different things